# OS X 10.8.4: Applescript giving syntax error for 'property list file'

Tags: macos, applescript, plist

I want to find whether or not a specific version of Firefox was installed on a Mac that may have one or more different versions of Firefox installed.  I can't simply use `version of application "Firefox"` because I may miss alternate installations of Firefox that way.  My Applescript code so far is:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set firefox_list to paragraphs of (do shell script "find /Applications -name Firefox.app")
    repeat with ff_installed in firefox_list
        -- get version
        set ff_ins_info to property list file (POSIX path of ff_installed & "/Contents/Info.plist")
        set ff_ins_version to (value of property list item "Bundle version" of ff_ins_info)
        display dialog ff_ins_version
    end repeat
end tell
```

Unfortunately I get an error message when I try to compile: `Syntax Error: Expected expression but found “property”.`  The best I can make out is that Applescript doesn't seem to recognize `property list file` as an object.  As I understand it, this should work after 10.5.

I've considered writing a shell script to look up the version number using Apple's PlistBuddy utility, but that seems even more complicated than this approach.  Am I left with `grep`ing through Plist XML directly at this point?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made 3 changes to get it working:

1. replaced `tell application "Finder"` with `tell application "System Events"`
2. left out `POSIX path of`
3. replaced `Bundle version` with `CFBundleVersion`

This is the final version

```
tell application "System Events"
    set firefox_list to paragraphs of (do shell script "find /Applications -name Firefox.app")
    repeat with ff_installed in firefox_list
        -- get version
        set ff_ins_info to property list file (ff_installed & "/Contents/Info.plist")
        set ff_ins_version to (value of property list item "CFBundleVersion" of ff_ins_info)
        display dialog ff_ins_version
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you!  How might I have known (other than simply having more experience dealing with Info.plist files) that what XCode displayed as "Bundle version" is actually tagged "CFBundleVersion"?  (Hmm, okay, I see OmniOutliner displayed it correctly, but I don't remember installing that...)  Anyway, this worked, I can move on, thanks again!